# Is there a way to get values of only resolved promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, promise.all

I'm calling multiple services which includes network calls and other asynchronous services in my JavaScript application.

At first I was invoking these promises one by one. In the long run it's getting hard to maintain since I'm invoking more services.

I read somewhere in the internet that we can use Promise.all() to group all promises and execute everything at a time.

The issue is, if any one of the promise is getting rejected all other promises are also getting rejected, this is not what I need.

I'm working in a status dashboard where I need to ping multiple services and show whether the service is up or not. By using Promise.all, it's not working in a way I wished.

Tried another method Promise.any(), but it just resolves when any one is resolved.

Took a look at MDN docs, there are many functions for promise it's overwhelming to me because I'm a beginner in JavaScript.

Currently I've created a very own service which takes care of calling all the promises and counts with the response. Is there any cleaner way to do it?

Comment: sound like you shouldn't put these promise together at first? why you can have one rejected and still process the data?

Comment: You may "enqueue" your promises into an Asynchronous Queue ([AQ](https://github.com/kedicesur/AQ)) and then control whatever you want to do with them. Get the resolving ones one after the other or even race them by neglecting the rejected ones. Try.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Promise.allSettled`, then filter out those that weren't fulfilled.

```js
Promise.allSettled([
  Promise.resolve(3),
  Promise.reject(4),
  Promise.resolve(5),
])
  .then((results) => {
    const allFulfilledValues = results
      .filter(r => r.status === 'fulfilled')
      .map(r => r.value);
    console.log(allFulfilledValues);
  });
```